# NodeJS, MySQL - JSON Stringify - Advanced query

Tags: mysql

I have an object in the table column saved using JSON.stringify and it looks like this:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "uID": 10
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "uID": 10
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "uID": 94
}]
```

I need a query that will check if a given column contains values e.g.

- I want uID = 10 and id = 2 will return
- I want uID = 10 and id = 5    will not return it
- I want uID = 10 and id = 2, uID = 94 and id = 0   will not return it
  (because uID = 94 and id = 0 is not here)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are querying programmatically where you can parse the JSON and then do the logic, I would recommend something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%"id": 1,"uID": 10%'
```

The `LIKE` keyword allows us to use wildcards (%) but still do an exact text match for what we define.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wildcard in the middle, but note that order matters with this strategy.

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%"id": 1%"id": 2%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I need it to work backwards too:] e.g. I have

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "uID": 10
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "uID": 55
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "uID": 94
}]

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%"uID": 55%"uID": 94%' <- will be working

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%"uID": 94%"uID": 55%' <- will be not working
```

Does not work "back"